# PHP Count Array Elements

Tags: php, arrays, count

hi can someone explain why this would return "An array consists of 0 elements." :

```
$arr = array(1,3,5); 
$count = count($arr); 
if ($count = 0) { echo "An array is empty."; } else { echo "An array has $count elements."; }
```

By the way, this is one a quiz i'm working through and i'm not sure why this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are assigning `$count` to 0 in your conditional statement

Instead of...

```
if ($count = 0)
```

Do this

```
if ($count === 0)
```

Comment: yes, check the docs here for a full explanation ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are going to check one logic means, check twice if we are using correct operators.

**Most of them doing the same mistake like ,**

```
if ($count = 0)   // here you are assigning the value to $count variable
```

Assign the values instead of compare the values.

```
if ($count == 0)  // here variable is compared
```

We can use more operators for comparing the logical condition.Such like ( >, <, >=, <=, == )