# Count total number of words in array

Tags: php, arrays, function, search, counting

I would like to count the words in this array and have them display as a total rather than how many times each word is displayed.

```
<?php
$array = array("abstract", "accident", "achilles", "acidwash", "afrojack", "aguilera");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Result

```
Array ( [abstract] => 1 [accident] => 1 [achilles] => 1 [acidwash] => 1 [afrojack] => 1 [aguilera] => 1 )
```

The result i would like

6

Comment: you mean, like... count() ?

Comment: i think so, the count() can count even the arrays element.

Comment: Did you try to search an answer???Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317612/count-number-of-values-in-array-with-a-given-value,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914175/php-count-array-elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this ?

```
echo count($array); //"prints" 6
```

Alternatively you can use `sizeof` too !

```
echo sizeof($array); //"prints" 6
```

Comment: In fairness it wasn't specified if this is indeed the case or not. In which case, what happens with a single string of multiple words, would the OP expect those to be counted as 1 word, or N words within said string.

Comment: Granted. But that's a massive lack of information, given the very different approaches required. Don't you think? Had the OP stated: $array = ("something", "something else", "something else again"); - In their current question, maybe everyone would've got the point? You can't start flaming folk for offering an answer, when the question is (if it is at all), fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `count()`. More information can be found here: https://www.php.net/count

Specifically:

```
$b[0]  = 7;
$b[5]  = 9;
$b[10] = 11;
$result = count($b);
// $result == 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the count function.

```
$array = array("abstract", "accident", "achilles", "acidwash", "afrojack", "aguilera");
print_r(count($array));
```

This will print 6. You could also assign the count to a variable.

```
$count = count($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `count` function in php:

```
echo count($array); // this will print lenght of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple words in one array value, try this approach:

```
$wordcount = str_word_count(implode(' ', $array));
```

It implodes the array and gets number of words in the returned string.

http://php.net/function.str-word-count.php
http://php.net/function.implode

If you want a function:

```
function array_word_count($array) {
    return str_word_count(implode(' ', $array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `count($array)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count()` function — it used count all elements in an array.

```
echo $count = count($array); //OP : 6
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/count

Comment: I dont know what is the reason for Downvoting? Mr.downvoter can you share the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_count = count(array_unique($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("abstract", "accident", "achilles", "acidwash", "afrojack", "aguilera");
print_r(sizeof($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count($array);
```

or

```
sizeof($array);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

https://www.php.net/sizeof