# How to count Array based on statement?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I use validate php function to filter badword. And my problem is this script can't count badword in a statement that I've input. How to count badword in a statement..?

For example: **You're badword1 and they badword2.**
 It's supposed to be 2 badword in that sentence.

**PHP**

```
function validasi($string,$banned_words) {
    foreach($banned_words as $banned_word) {
        if(stristr($string,$banned_word)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
$banned_words = array('badword1','badword2','badword3','badword4','badword5','badword6','badword7');
$teks = $_POST['teks'];
if (!validasi($teks,$banned_words)) {
    echo count(!validasi($teks,$banned_words));
    echo 'blocked!';
}else{
    echo 'Text valid';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="validasi.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="teks">
  <input type="submit" value="Validasi">
</form>
```

**Output**

> 1 !blocked.

**Expected Result**

> 2 !blocked

Comment: `!validasi($teks,$banned_words)` is either `true` or `false`. http://php.net/count: *If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface, 1 will be returned.*

Comment: Your validasi function is only returning a Boolean value (true/false), and "true" boolean values are printed as "1" in PHP. You will need to instead track the number of counts within that function, and then print that count instead.

Comment: If the input is "*badword1 and badword1*", should the result be `1` or `2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Count Array Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914175/php-count-array-elements)

Comment: it's different..  I've edited the title...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do this

```
function validasi($string,$banned_words) {
$badWordCount = 0;
foreach($banned_words as $banned_word) {
if(stristr($string,$banned_word)){
$badWordCount++;
}
}
return $badWordCount;
}
$banned_words = array('badword1','badword2','badword3','badword4','badword5','badword6','badword7');
$teks = $_POST['teks'];
$badWordsCount2 = validasi($teks,$banned_words);
if ($badWordsCount2 != 0) {
echo $badWordsCount2;
echo 'blocked!';
}else{
echo 'Text valid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script also don't count extra the words if they are using the same word multiple times in a string. Below here is a script i should use.

```
function getBadWords(){
    $db_con = new PDO('dsn', 'use', 'pass'); // You PDO connection
    $query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROm tb_bannedwords");
    $query->execute();
    $return = array();
    while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $data = $return[] = $row->banned_words;
    }
    return $return;
}
function validate($string){
    $banned_words = getBadWords();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($banned_words as $banned_word){
        $wordCount = substr_count($string, $banned_word);
        if($wordCount > 0){
            $count = $count + $wordCount;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
$teks = 'You\'re badword1 and they badword2 with badword1';
if(validate($teks) > 0){
    echo validate($teks) . ' blocked!';
}else{
    echo 'Text valid';
}
```

Comment: Thank you... But I have a question.. If I get data from database,, how to change it to array?
`$query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROm tb_bannedwords");
    $query->execute();
    $return= array();
    while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $data = $return[] = $row->banned_words;
    }
  $count = 0;
    foreach($data as $banned_word){
    $wordCount = substr_count($string, $banned_word);
    if($wordCount > 0){
        $count = $count + $wordCount;
    }
}
return $count;
  }`